# Keras flow_from_directory function returning error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, spyder

My code for Keras in Python looks like:

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                target_size=(64, 64),
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode='binary')
```

I am continuously getting this error:

> [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
>   'dataset/training_set'

I have confirmed in every way that this path is correct but it still throws the error. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that the reason I was getting the above error was because **my path was very long**.

You can only see 'dataset/training_set' in the error but overall python is of course picking the entire path. And it so happens that my path was very long.

Instead of getting the error about length of path, I got the error that it can not find the path.

I just changed the length of path by changing some folder names and it worked.

Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: Did not fix the error for me.